# Two AMP forms, one <div submit-success>

Tags: amp-html

In my page I have 2 AMP forms, one ***submit button*** that is placed in the 1st form and one ***div submit-success*** that is placed in the second form. How can I show in the 2nd form the status of the 1st form submit?

Answer (score 0):

Using `amp-bind` you can do this :

In 1st form set the response of form by using below syntax

```
on="submit-success:AMP.setState({ statusForm1 : event.response.message })"
```

In 2nd form the status of the 1st form by using

```
<div class="" [text]=" 'Form1 status is :' + statusForm1"> </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't do that. This will not help. I need to show HTML in the second form, and not pure text. What would be alternative?